# How to use correctly CURL in Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome, curl, google-chrome-storage

I am trying to upload new file to chrome web store with curl command.

For example:

```
Process process = curlLogic.CurlConsolecCommand("curl -H \"Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlwFBWeaYiJBH8mQ3oHHlb_khSuJF02zFszBkTJnajajpzKwaeG0b9CTXdY3VseMwI-JPbRRNFZpr-NZaaCB_Mh3A\"  -H \"x-goog-api-version: 2\" -X POST -T /Users/mac/Downloads/file_name -v https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items");

public Process CurlConsolecCommand (String url){
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process process = runtime.exec(url);
    int resultCode = process.waitFor();
    log.info("resultCode : " + resultCode); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       builder.append(line);
       builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    String result = builder.toString();

    if (resultCode == 0) {
        // all is good
    } 

    log.info("is: " + process.getInputStream().toString());
    log.info("es: " + process.getErrorStream().toString());
} catch (Throwable cause) {
    log.severe("can not CurlConsolecCommand e = "+ cause.toString());
}
```

Using this code I cant get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>411.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I used chrome web store publish api:
   https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#beforeyoubegin

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: So add that header and use the `file.length`

Comment: I tried that..I use curl \ -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlwKBaherWq9IWKds15GfTEwjrmSN8sQtGwSm32ORalcKw_w4uhg35_tpBWAhytyoHJf4f_sTLQR8pgDf586jLcoAXYbgNytentx2LqgqJwCxAWnRIsSs7GTaz3vLA" \ -H "x-goog-api-version: 2" \ -H "Content-Length: 740624" \ -X POST \ -T /Users/mac/Downloads/ProntoBaron_3.25.10.zip \ -v \ https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items

Comment: still not working

Comment: @canillas you have more suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried your call from another context? I.e. try to do the call from Postman anc copy the curl code that it generates if it works.

Comment: I tried to do it from terminal and it works @canillas